# Android Service - issue with BindService when use it along with startService

Tags: android, service, android-service

I am newbie to android platform. Currently working on streaming radio application.

I want to make the Application, starts the audio playback and continuos to play even application goes to background.

I have created a Service using **startService()** so that play back will continue even though application goes to background. I have also used **bindService()** to get a serviceConnection reference to perform RPC calls with service.

Application starts the service and playback started correctly and bindService able to get the reference and able to make RPC calls, everything works fine till app goes to background.

I am calling **bindService()** and **unBindService()** call in **onResume()** and **onPause()** of main activity.

> When app goes to background, playback continues with out any issue. **unBindservice()** call detach the service connection and **onUnbind(Intent)** method got invoked in Service class. No issue so far.
>
> when application comes to foreground(while service is running and playback continues),
>   I am not getting the service connection reference (**onServiceConnected()** is not getting invoked), even though **bindService()** is called in activity **onResume()** method. i have also verified Service class **onBind(Intent)** method is also not getting invoked.

I am struggling with this issue for past few days.

What is the recommended approach to use the **startService()** and **bindService()** with user defined Android Service.

Any help to resolve this issue, highly appreciated.

Activity onResume/onPause Code.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate => " + getIntent());
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // set the default network preference, if it is not already set
    setDefaultNetwork();

    // initialize the navigation tab bars
    initializeTabBar();

    mPlayerController = AudioPlayerController.getInstance(this);

    mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

    mRemoteControlReceiver = new RemoteControlReceiver();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(
            "android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON");
    registerReceiver(mRemoteControlReceiver, filter);

    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d(TAG,"onResume");
    mPlayerController.bindService();
    restoreAppState();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.d(TAG,"onPause");
    mPlayerController.unBindService();
    storeAppState();
}
```

Controller class has service related start/stop/bind/unbind methods

```java
    public void bindService() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClassName("com.vikkrithik.radio.indradio",
            "com.vikkrithik.radio.indradio.AudioPlayerService");
    Log.d(TAG, "bindService Context " + mPlayerContext
            + " serviceConnection => " + audioServiceConnection);
    mPlayerContext.bindService(intent, audioServiceConnection, 0);
}

public void unBindService() {
    mPlayerContext.unbindService(audioServiceConnection);
    Log.d(TAG, "unBindService done context => " + mPlayerContext
            + " serviceConnection => " + audioServiceConnection);
}

private ServiceConnection audioServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onServiceConnected " + name);
        mAudioService = AudioPlayerServiceInterface.Stub
                .asInterface(service);
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onServiceDisconnected " + name);
        mAudioService = null;
    }
};
/**
 * Start the AudioService
 * 
 */
public void startAudioService(Station station) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClassName("com.vikkrithik.radio.indradio",
            "com.vikkrithik.radio.indradio.AudioPlayerService");

    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putString("station_url", station.getUrl());
    extras.putString("station_name", station.getStationName());
    intent.putExtras(extras);
    mCurrentStation = station;
    mPlayerContext.startService(intent);
    bindService();
    Log.d(TAG, "startService called");
}

public void stopAudioService() {
    //
    // Check if AudioService is already created
    //
    if (null == mAudioService)
        return;

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClassName("com.vikkrithik.radio.indradio",
            "com.vikkrithik.radio.indradio.AudioPlayerService");
    mPlayerContext.stopService(intent);
    Log.d(TAG, "stopAudioService done");
}
```

Service Class Methods

```java
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onBind invoked");
    return audioServiceStub;
}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG,"onUnbind invoked");
    return super.onUnbind(intent);
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
    audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    mNetworkStatusReceiver = new NetworkStatusReceiver();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(
            ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
    registerReceiver(mNetworkStatusReceiver, filter);

    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
            .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(
                    mNetworkStatusReceiver);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestory");
    stopPlayback();

    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
            .unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(
                    mNetworkStatusReceiver);
    unregisterReceiver(mNetworkStatusReceiver);
    cancelNotification();
    audioServiceStub = null;
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

**Logcat output**

> **when app launches**

TabbarMainActivity(15432): onResume
AudioPlayerController(15432): bindService Context com.vikkrithik.radio.indradio.TabbarMainActivity@4150fdb8 serviceConnection => com.vikkrithik.radio.indradio.AudioPlayerController$1@418a2d30

> **When play button is pressed**

AudioPlayerController(15432): bindService Context com.vikkrithik.radio.indradio.TabbarMainActivity@4150fdb8 serviceConnection => com.vikkrithik.radio.indradio.AudioPlayerController$1@418a2d30

AudioPlayerController(15432): startService called

AudioPlayerService(15432): onCreate

AudioPlayerService(15432): onBind invoked **onBind() invoked**

AudioPlayerService(15432): onStartCommand with IndetntIntent { cmp=xxxx (has extras) }

AudioPlayerController(15432): onServiceConnected   ComponentInfo{com.vikkrithik.radio.indradio/com.vikkrithik.radio.indradio.AudioPlayerService} **onServiceConnected invoked**

> **when back button is pressed, app goes to background**

TabbarMainActivity(15432): finish called

TabbarMainActivity(15432): onPause

AudioPlayerController(15432): unBindService done context => com.vikkrithik.radio.indradio.TabbarMainActivity@4150fdb8 serviceConnection => com.vikkrithik.radio.indradio.AudioPlayerController$1@418a2d30 **onPause() calls unBindService()**

AudioPlayerService(15432): onUnbind invoked   **unBind Got invoked in Service**

TabbarMainActivity(15432): onDestroy

> **App comes to forground**

TabbarMainActivity(15432): onCreate => Intent { cmp=xxxx }

TabbarMainActivity(15432): onResume  **bindService is called from onResume**

AudioPlayerController(15432): bindService Context com.vikkrithik.radio.indradio.TabbarMainActivity@4150fdb8 serviceConnection => com.vikkrithik.radio.indradio.AudioPlayerController$1@418a2d30

> **After playback is stopped**

AudioPlayerService(15432): stop

AudioPlayerService(15432): reset

AudioPlayerController(15432): stopAudioService done

AudioPlayerFragment(15432): removeVisualizer

AudioPlayerService(15432): onDestory

Comment: Can you show us the `DEBUG` level LogCat of what happens when you start the app, bring it to the background, and open it again?

Comment: It looks ok but you don't show us the onResume() and onPause() code, or the messages printed.  Have you tried moving this stuff to the onCreate() and onDestroy() methods and keeping a reference to it accross pauses/stops.  You might then just need to check the reference in onresume (by calling a ping method and catching any exception and re-connect).

Comment: I have updated the post with the onResume()/onPause() code. DEBUG message also included. @hack_on i have tried to move the bind and unBind service call to onCreate and onDestroy(). The same problem happens when i press the Back button to close the app and relaunch it.

Answer (score 4):

I have not been able to just "see" the problem, so I have created an app that does most of the things you need as a basis of a solution.  It does not do networking or use the real MediaPlayer, but the service has a background thread that does output audio.  You can start and stop the audio from the two buttons.  I was able to hit the back button, and keep hearing the service, then start the app from the icon and stop and re-start the audio playing.  I thought you may be able to follow my steps, and if it works with your device, then start adding the MediaPlayer and networking code into a functional service.

I used the following [tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Android_Remote_Bound_Services_%E2%80%93_A_Worked_Example) as a basis for the service code which uses messages and not Stub/interfaces to the service.

It is based on a new Android project in Eclipse, then I just added two buttons and gave them new text and Ids.  The rest is here:

First the content I put in the MainActivity that eclipse created:

```
private final static String TAG = "MainActivity";
// Service stuff
Messenger myService = null;
boolean isBound;
private Button startBut;
private Button stopBut;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    startBut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startAudio);
    startBut.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            try
            {
                if (myService != null && isBound)
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Service Connected! sending start request");
                    Message msg = Message.obtain();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("MyString", "start");

                    msg.setData(bundle);
                    myService.send(msg);
                }
            }
            catch (Throwable th)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "error sending start", th);
            }
        }
    });

    stopBut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopAudio);
    stopBut.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            try
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "Service Connected! sending stop request");

                Message msg = Message.obtain();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("MyString", "stop");

                msg.setData(bundle);
                myService.send(msg);
            }
            catch (Throwable th)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "error sending start", th);
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();

    unBindService();
}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    Log.d(TAG, "Resuming: binding to service");
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.audioservice.AudioPlayerService");

    // Start the service ourselves because we don't want it to stop when the activity/application does.
    startService(intent);
    bindService(intent, myConnection, 0);
}

private ServiceConnection myConnection = new ServiceConnection() 
{
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        myService = new Messenger(service);
        isBound = true;
        Log.d(TAG, "Service Connected!");
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        myService = null;
        isBound = false;
    }
};

public void unBindService() 
{
    this.unbindService(myConnection);
    Log.d(TAG, "unBindService done context => " 
            + " serviceConnection => " + myConnection);
}
```

Next, a small insert to the Manifest file:

```
<service android:enabled="true"  android:name="com.example.audioservice.AudioPlayerService"
         android:process=":my_process" >
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.audioservice.AudioPlayerService" >
         </action>
      </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Finally the content of the AudioPlayerService class:

```
public class AudioPlayerService extends Service
{
private static final String TAG = "AudioPlayerService";
AudioManager audioManager;
private boolean playing = false;
private Player player;

class IncomingHandler extends Handler
{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
        Bundle data = msg.getData();
        String dataString = data.getString("MyString");
        if ("start".equalsIgnoreCase(dataString))
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Got a start request");
            // Start playing
            playing = true;
        }
        else if ("stop".equalsIgnoreCase(dataString))
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Got a stop request");
            // Stop playing
            playing = false;
        }
    }
}

@SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
final Messenger myMessenger = new Messenger(new IncomingHandler());

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
{
    Log.d(TAG, "onBind invoked");
    return myMessenger.getBinder();
}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent)
{
    Log.d(TAG, "onUnbind invoked");
    return super.onUnbind(intent);
}

@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
    audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    audioManager.loadSoundEffects();
    player = new Player();
    player.start();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestory");
    stopPlayback();

    super.onDestroy();
}

private void stopPlayback()
{
    playing = false;
}

// Pointless Thread to let us know the service is still doing its thing
class Player extends Thread
{
    public void run()
    {
        int x = 7;
        while (1 < x)
        {
            try
            {
                if (playing)
                {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                    Log.d(TAG, ".");
                    audioManager.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEY_CLICK);
                }
            }
            catch (Throwable th)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "error in Player", th);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the sample code. will check it and update you. Your code uses Messenger where as my code does not. Not sure how Messenger will make the difference.

Answer (score 0):

I see these problems with an app that runs a service that records vehicle trips with GPS.
At the press of a button the service is started and goes on with its recording that can continue for hours if so needed. At the press of a stop button the service terminates. During recording there is an interface to communicate certain live data that display on the UI so the bind/unbind handles the interruption/reconnect cycles due to rotation, backgrounding/resuming the app and so on.

As long as the service runs there is no issues. But when I stop the recording meaning I stop the service but continue to maintain the binding/unbinding solution with the service class,
the service leak messages appear.  What I might try to do is to redesign things so that I either (1) care to bind unbind only while the service is running, or (2) run the service at all times during the app lifetime and add ways to tell it to begin or stop recording and let it "idle" at other times. Maybe (1) is the way to go and the approach to maintain a service connection also to an non-running service might not be the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to rebind, make sure you return true from `onUnbind` and in that case `onRebind` will be called in the `Service` when you call `bindService` from the `Activity`.

#### `Service.java`

```
@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        super.onUnbind(intent);
        /* logic */
        return true; // future binds from activity will call onRebind
}

@Override
public void onRebind(Intent intent) {
    // Is called when activity issues a `bindService` after an `undbindService`
    super.onRebind(intent);
    /*logic*/
}
```